# how to check video camera is available on iPhone

Tags: iphone, camera

is there any way to check video camera capability available on iPhone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the camera related availability support is exposed through the `UIImagePickerController`. A bit tricker thing is detection of Video Camera. You can detect the presence of a video camera in a iOS device using the following method.

```
- (BOOL) isVideoCameraAvailable
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    NSArray *sourceTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:picker.sourceType];
    [picker release];

    if (![sourceTypes containsObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie ]){

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this code (based on UIDevice) which helped me with this issue:

https://github.com/MugunthKumar/DeviceHelper